# error in adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I have two tables: `tab1,tab2`

I want  add a foreign key to tab2 and wrote this query

```
ALTER TABLE tab2
ADD FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES tab1(name)
```

But I get this error:

```
error 1005(HY000):can't create table 'club.#sql-6f0_2' (errno:150)
```

What is wrong?

```
Edit

i write this tables only for test.

tab1

name char(20) private key

lname char(20)


tab2

ssn int private key

name char(20)
```

Comment: What database management system (DBMS) are you using? Also, show us what the table structure is:

`show create table tab1;`
`show create table tab2;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered this for you about an hour ago in a comment on your other question, but here it is again:

You can get details on that error by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and reading the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

The most likely reasons for this failure:

- tab1.name and tab2.name are not exactly the same data type
- tab1.name is not unique

Comment: +1: The 1005/150 error is documented, too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alter table tab2
add foreign key my_key(name) references tab1(name)
```

maybe Your key should have a name?

Answer (score 0):

You can not define Foreign Keys on default MySQL storage engines (ISAM, MyISAM), use InnoDB as engine, then add foreign key constraints.

Comment: The error implies that the tables are both InnoDB. MyISAM wouldn't fail with an error, it would let the ALTER TABLE complete and silently do nothing since it doesn't have foreign keys.